"*A* ~10% reduction" or "*AN* ~10% reduction"
I am reading a document related to programming, where a reduction in something is described, and it occurred to me that it was written different than what I would've done it.
The text in the document was:

..., an ~10% reduction in binary size.

when I read it, it occurred to me that I would've probably used a instead of an, but that's because I was focusing on the 10, as in ten.
Maybe the ~ might, or should?, be read as approximately, and then an is correct.
Is it actually correct? This is just to satisfy my own curiosity so if this is something that depends, well, then it depends.

Apologies if this post is not perfect english though, as I'm not a native english speaker or writer. Also, please retag this question if isn't off-topic as I couldn't determine which tag would fit better than grammar.

How would you read/pronounce "~"? That said, I doubt it matters much.

Good question, when I read stuff aloud, like if I'm reading a document to others, I think I would've just unconciously reworded it, so I probably would've read that exact statement as "approximately a 10% reduction in binary size", but the exact statement, read as written, would probably be "an approximately 10% reduction in size", so I guess "an" is the correct word here. Again, this was just to satisfy my curiosity :) Even if ~ would be read as "estimated", depending on the context, "an" is still the right thing

@LasseV.Karlsen The ~ would read as the adjective "approximate". rather than the adverb.

The usual pronouncement is 'choice between a/an is determined solely by the pronunciation of the following word, letter etc' (we'll ignore the 'an historic?' grey area). But as I always expand NP to noun phrase, I use 'a NP'. Doubtless some will object. I'd correspondingly use 'an' in your example, especially as ~10% is never read out as 'tilde 10 percent'. But good luck finding this in a style guide.

@Greybeard "Before a number the tilde can mean 'approximately'; '~42' means 'approximately 42'. " [Wikipedia]

@EdwinAshworth. Yes. I am aware of that but in the Wiki example refers to numbers, and here we have a {10 percent reduction}. We would have "a generous 10% reduction" not "a generously 10% reduction"

@Greybeard But that is a combination of 'a generous reduction' and 'a 10% reduction', not a reduction that is somewhat over 10%. On the other hand, 'a/an ~10% reduction in  size' means a reduction in size that is approximately 10%. The premodifiers are stacked rather than coordinated in this latter case.

Honestly I would have read the tilde aloud as "circa"! But I'm not sure the document was written with a level of care that merits this much discussion. This is a good example of why many style guides would advise that the word be written out.

@AndyBonner "circa" is usually used with dates, not used much with amounts.

If I were reading it aloud my pronunciation of the tilde might be approximately in a more formal setting, and roughly in a less formal setting.

@Peter yes, but with "an" I'd end up at "approximately" even in a setting where "roughly" (or "something like" or other informal terms) would otherwise fit better

@ChrisH, yes, and about would also work. I don't think it is appropriate to prescribe whether a or an should be used in this context; the tilde is a symbol for a concept, not for a word. I would use a as the default when it is not known how the symbol will be pronounced.

@Peter that's a sensible way of looking at it. While I use ~ quite a bit to indicate approximation, even in sentences, I've never faced this. Something like "an increase of ~10%"  avoids the issue but to me seems more natural anyway.

Does it help to compare   "a ten percent increase" vs. "an eight percent increase"  The latter starts with a vowel.

This question is similar to: What article do we use before a symbol? Is it "an @" or "a @"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DjinTonic I think my question is quite similar, if not identical, to the question you linked, so I voted to close mine as a duplicate. It's not that I think it was a separate question, and that's why I posted it, it's more that it's quite difficult to search stack exchange sites for similar posts, where the similiary is based on something other than the same words being used. This is actually one area I hope AI can help with, being able to identify similar topics, where different words are actually being used so a direct search would turn up nothing, but an AI might see a similarity.

In my opinion, the text is bad because it invites the reader to question it like this.  It would have been much better to say "... about a 10% reduction ... " so the a/an question doesn't break the reader's concentration on the meaning of the text.
